# How can I create an exact replica of a file in notepad?

Tags: notepad

[image]

How can I create an exact replica of this file in notepad? In particular how do I achieve multiple lines or split the lines exactly as in the picture ?

Comment: By pressing return at the end of the line. By pressing tab before you start a paragraph. You should probably look at ana lternative notepad which is more feature-rish... such as Notepad++ or others.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: you're also not going to be able to justify your margins like you can in Word; if you're trying to avoid retyping it you could probably throw it into a .pdf, select, copy, and paste the text somewhere else

Comment: formatting isn't the issue. its splitting the line in note pad to match lines in the image attached

Comment: or is there a way in which I can find out if the enter/return tab has been used in a txt file to split lines

Comment: In what format is the original file? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: actually - what is your end goal here? because other than turning on word wrapping, using tabs, and/or terminating lines by manually pressing enter as previous comments have stated - there’s not more you’re going to be able to do with Notepad

Comment: the end goal is to simply type out a given text (a jpg file) in note pad with least errors. its a school project for my kid with negative markings for each category of errors one of which is the wrong enter tabs. This set me thinking - why would anybody make a mistake on enter tabs until I realised that in notepad, a line is continuous unless one manually hit the enter button and could there then be a trap laid out with kids hitting the enter button to split the lines to exactly match the given picture when actually its the wrong way to achieve the said result.

Comment: so the easiest way to exactly replicate the text (as per the attached file) unformatted into notepad would be to just type out the text and split the lines as per the image by hitting the enter button at the appropriate position. but is this the right way - given that kids would be given negative marks for each enter buttons hit wrongly.

Comment: That's also justified text which is not supported by Notepad.

Comment: Yes you are correct. but the text in the notepad not justified is fine

Answer (score 1):

The picture you showed me suggests that you have a scanned page. If so, run an OCR program to scan your picture then save the result as a text file. You can open it in Notepad and make the desired modifications.